# Configure multiple outbound SSL setting in Websphere Liberty?

Tags: ssl, websphere-liberty

We're migrating from WAS 8.5.5.2 to Liberty and currently we have set up 3 "Dynamic outbound endpoint SSL configurations".  Below is masked data but shows the extract from security.xml:

```
<dynamicSSLConfigSelections
    xmi:id="DynamicSSLConfigSelection_1111222333444"
    name="Client3CertSSLSettings"
    description="SSL Settings for client 3"
    dynamicSelectionInfo="*,wss.microso.net,443"
    certificateAlias="qa_sha2"
    sslConfig="SSLConfig_1"
    managementScope="ManagementScope_1"/>
<dynamicSSLConfigSelections
    xmi:id="DynamicSSLConfigSelection_1111222333555"
    name="Client1CertSSLSettings"
    description="SSL Settings for client 1"
    dynamicSelectionInfo="*,qa1.dummysite.net,*|*,qa2.dummysite.net,*|*,qa3.dummysite.net,*"
    certificateAlias="client1_qa"
    sslConfig="SSLConfig_1"
    managementScope="ManagementScope_1"/>
<dynamicSSLConfigSelections
    xmi:id="DynamicSSLConfigSelection_1111222333666"
    name="Client2CertSSLSettings"
    description="SSL client certificate Settings for client 2"
    dynamicSelectionInfo="*,ws.website.biz,443"
    sslConfig="SSLConfig_1"
    managementScope="ManagementScope_1"/>
```

It seems from IBM docs, they only allow one entry of outboundSSLRef in the .

Is it possible to configure multiple outbound SSL settings in websphere liberty?  How can we translate this to the Liberty format?

---

IBM docs researched:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_config_ssl_outbound.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_liberty_ssl_defaults.html

Comment: Off-topic. Belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there is only support for 1 outbound SSL configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  I also found a whitepaper on the differences between traditional WAS and Liberty, hope it helps others: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/documentation/ChoosingTraditionalWASorLiberty-16.0.0.4.pdf